# Why is Illegal reference to net "portA"

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

why am I getting this error ?

It's when I try to assign values to the inout wires.
How can I fix that?

```
module test (portA,enable,InNotOut)
input enable , InNotOut ;
inout portA ;
always @ (enable)
begin
if (InNotOut)
portA = 8'bzzzz_zzzz; 
end
endmodule
```

Comment: An `inout` should be assigned with `assign` statements and not inside an `always` block.

Answer (score 0):

in your case the inout `portA` is a `net`, `wire`. Wires can only be assigned with the `assign` statement (or by connection to an output port).

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your code, but it does not look right in any case. Most likely you need something like this bus assignment:

```
assign portA = (enable && InNotOut) ? someValue :  'z;
```

Sinced the port is a wire, it cannot store a value and must always be driven, so `someValue` is required. This way it drives the bus either with the someValue or with high impedance value if enable condition is off.

in SV you can use just `'z` to assigh all bits with 'z'.